# Getting data from generated form in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code setup:

http://jsfiddle.net/bABHU/2/

Had to change it a little bit to get it all on jsfiddle but the problem i'm having is the data from the first from gets put into the query string to send off to the ajax call, but the form elements generated after that (which comes from a JSON call) don't get submitted when clicking the next button again.

So when you get to the second question how can I submit the 'answer' input that was generated. - see the console for the outputs.

Hope that makes sense.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you are replacing your entire `<form>` element with the new HTML content from question 2. Replace `$('.FinderOptionsInner').html` with `$('#formStep').html`

See http://jsfiddle.net/M3eZp/1/

Comment: @user1380591: If this answer was helpful, you should vote it up. If it solved your question, you should [mark it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 1):

When you replace the markup for findOptionsInner, you obliterate the form itself. Hence it not serializing. Also, you have no close tag for your form.

```
<form action="" method="post" name="formStep" id="formStep">
<div class="FinderOptionsInner">
    <p>
    <label class="label_check">
      <input type="radio" name="answer" value="1" id="answer_0" />
      Answer 1</label>
    <br />
    <label class="label_check">
      <input type="radio" name="answer" value="2" id="answer_1" />
      Answer 2</label>
    <br />
  </p>
</div>
</form>

<div class="nextButton-step1 nextButton">Next
</div>
```

Works just fine (notice that I've also fixed the close tags for form and the div at the bottom).